# Conditional caching on shiny's bindCache

Tags: r, caching, shiny

Let's say I have a reactive like this somewhere in my `shiny` server:

```
my_reactive <- reactive({
    build_result(input$x)
})
```

As of Shiny 1.6, I can cache its result with `bindCache` like this:

```
my_reactive <- reactive({
    build_result(input$x)
}) %>% bindCache(input$x)
```

Now let's say that I don't know if I should cache the result before I get the result of `build_result`.

```
build_result("input")
# $should_cache
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $result
# [1] "output"
```

Is there any way to tell `bind_cache` to cache the result of this reactive's evaluation only when `should_cache` is `TRUE`?
In case someone is curious as to why I would want that, `build_result` calls an API where `should_cache==FALSE` actually means "I need more time to compute this, this is only a temporary result, next time you ask it will be better, but I didn't want to block the whole server, so here's what I have so far." (yeah, my APIs can be quite chatty).